# How can I manually access a third-dimension javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to access a third level node in an array using the indexes in it, but I can't access it, I tried a lot of ways that I found here on SO but I don't want to iterate through it, I want to get it manually.

```
var data = [
   {code:1,
      label:'John Doe', 
      tasks:[{
         code:1,
         label: 'AnyProject',
         starts:'2016/1/25',
         ends:'2016/2/25'}]
}];
```

**What I want to do (theoretically)**:

> data[0].tasks.code

Comment: `data[0].tasks[0].code`. `tasks` is an **array** and you want to access the first element from that array, so use `tasks[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[0].tasks[0].code`

Inside `data array` you have `tasks` and inside task array you have property `code`.

`[]` is an array you can use index to look inside.

`{}` is an object you can access using `.`

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, and providing the actual syntax +1

Answer (score 2):

```
data[0].tasks[0].code
```

tasks is an Array so you need to access it like an array.